# Not able to make changes to any files on digitalocean hosted website

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

My website is hosted on digitalocean droplet Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Since yesterday when I am making any changes to my files on the server. The server don't reflect changes in the website.

I have the following observation:

1.When I am making changes to a file. Only the first change is being updated on the website. Any subsequent change is not being shown on the website.

2. I am able to add new files. So when I add a new file for example testing.php . It is being shown in the link www.example.com/testing.php.
   But When I delete this file from my server. The link is still working same as before. Which means that it is showing the same old file on the link www.example.com/testing.php.
3. All https links are working fine. I am able to make changes and these changes are being shown on the website. 
   But http links are not showing any updates made by me.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: yes. I cleared the cache.